# Creating data from web tables with import.io failed - other tools?

Tags: tool-request, web-crawling

I found this site with solar system moon orbit data:  [Table of moons in solar system](http://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/moons_table.html).

I ran that through the http://import.io site and it only came up with Jupiter data. Is there a more comprehensive tool that will identify multiple tables and import into a single table?
(I also tried the import.io desktop app).

Comment: ScraperWiki and Kimono are similar-ish to import.io

Comment: Copying the HTML table to Excel does the job too and doesn't require too too much clean up (if you dont expect the data to update often)

Comment: `TableTools2` for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabletools2/) can copy tables directly.

Answer (score 3):

[Data Scraping Studio](http://www.datascraping.co) can do this and it's free software.

I just created a scraping agent using this tool and extracted all tables into one using a REGEX parser. The extracted data should be exactly what you need.

Note: I wrote the REGEX for `TD` tag with links. You can modify the pattern to get both linked/non-linked using Regex OR condition.

[image: Orbit website scraping sample]

Comment: Here is the REGEX link to test/modify http://rubular.com/r/aWmcYCgtfH

Answer (score 2):

you can use google docs `importHtml` functionality to get what you want. add `=ImportHtml("URL", "table", num)` into a spread sheet, replacing `URL` with the HTML document's URL, and `num` with the HTML `<table>`'s number in the source code. The `<table>`'s number in the source code is simply based off the number of them are being used in the markup, and its order regarding to that number. so if you want the first table you come across in the HTML, put `1` for `num`.
I threw together a google spread sheet that pulls in the first two tables from the moons document you linked to, and i separated them with a row marking Table 1, Table 2; the first two rows are just info, first is the importHtml function, second is the url you wanted. Its not perfect by any means, but it works.
I've also used this allowing only one import statement per sheet; so I create a new sheet, past the import function, and alter the table number per sheet. I went ahead and set up two new sheets doing this to show you what i mean.
Again, not perfect, but something I've done to clean it up a bit and keep everything where I want it. Below is the spread sheet function to get the first table, then the second, and finally a link to the spread sheet for you to view/copy/etc. Please note that I broke them up into separate lines for readability, this should be one line placed into one table cell:

```
 =ImportHtml("http://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/moons_table.html",  
 "table",  
 1)  
=ImportHtml("http://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/moons_table.html",  
 "table",  
 2)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16INpQMP7dyhtTICZ3ft1wbdf1NkBgCec-Sg6IpFMRcw/edit?usp=sharing